# Equivalence Relations and functions on partitions of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

let $f$ be a function on $A$ onto $B$.  Define an equivalence relation $E$ in $A$ by: $aEb$ if and only if $f(a)=f(b)$.

Define a function $\phi$ on $A/E$ by $\phi([a]_{E})=f(a)$.

Hint: Verify that $\phi([a]_{E})=\phi([a']_{E}) $ if $[a]_{E} = [a']_{E}$

I know that A/E is a partition of A.

I know that a binary relation $F$ is called a function if $aFb$ and $aFc$ implies $b=c$ for any $a, b, \text {  and  } c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $\phi$ is a function, you must follow the hint. If $[a]_E=[a']_E$, then what can we say about $f(a)$ and $f(a')$? What then can be said about $\phi\left([a]_E\right)$ and $\phi\left([a']_E\right)$? You'll need to keep the definitions of $E,\phi$ in mind.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Suppose that $\langle [a]_E,x\rangle\in \phi$ and $[a]_E=[a']_E$, then $x=f(a)=f(a')$, conclude the wanted conclusion.

**Bonus points:** Show that $\phi$ is injective!

**More bonus points:** Show that every equivalence relation is actually induced like this by some function $f$.

(If you do both the bonus points thingies (*they are quite short actually*), then you have completely understood the topic.)

Comment: @amWhy: Yes. Restating the problem makes it clearer sometimes. In fact, if you think about it, most of basic proofs which are by bi-implications are restatements of the problem until you derive the conclusion!

Comment: Yes, indeed. You're very right about that! :-)  I was trying to think of a way to provide a hint, and came up with pretty much what you posted. Half (or more) of the battle seems to lie in understanding what's being asked.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I really wasn't sure what the question was asking.  It read like a statement, rather than a question.  Am I on the right track to say:  If $ \varphi ( [a]_{E}) = \varphi ([a']_{E})$ then $f(a) = f(a')$ therefore $aEa'$ can I then conclude that $[a]_{E}=[a']_{E}$ ?

Comment: @Sarah: Recall the theorem about equivalence classes. If they have elements in common then they are equal. If we assume that $a\mathrel{E}a'$, can we conclude that $[a]_E$ and $[a']_E$ have any elements in common?